# Does Realm support SELECT FOR UPDATE style read locking

Tags: realm

I've spent a fair amount of time looking into the Realm database mechanics and I can't figure out if Realm is using row level read locks under the hood for data selected during write transactions.

As a basic example, imagine the following "queue" logic

assume the queue has an arbitrary number of jobs (we'll say 5 jobs)

```
 async getNextJob() {

    let nextJob = null;

    this.realm.write(() => {

      let jobs = this.realm.objects('Job')
        .filtered('active == FALSE')
        .sorted([['priority', true], ['created', false]]);

      if (jobs.length) {
        nextJob = jobs[0];
        nextJob.active = true;
      }

    });

    return nextJob;

  }
```

If I call getNextJob() 2 times concurrently, if row level read blocking isn't occurring, there's a chance that nextJob will return the same job object when we query for jobs.

Furthermore, if I have outside logic that relies on up-to-date data in read logic (ie job.active == false when it actually is true at current time) I need the read to block until update transactions complete. MVCC reads getting stale data do not work in this situation.

If read locks are being set in write transactions, I could make sure I'm always reading the latest data like so

```
let active = null;
this.realm.write(() => {

  const job = this.realm.pseudoQueryToGetJobByPrimaryKey();
  active = job.active;

});

// Assuming the above write transaction blocked the read until 
// any concurrent updates touching the same job committed
// the value for active can be trusted at this point in time.
if (active === false) {
  // code to start job here
}
```

So basically, TL;DR does Realm support SELECT FOR UPDATE?

Postgresql

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html

MySql

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So basically, TL;DR does Realm support SELECT FOR UPDATE?

Well if I understand the question correctly, the answer is slightly trickier than that.

If there is no Realm Object Server involved, then `realm.write(() =>` disallows any other writes at the same time, and updates the Realm to its latest version when the transaction is opened.

If there is Realm Object Server involved, then I think this still stands locally, but the Realm Sync manages the updates from remote, in which case the conflict resolution rules apply for remote data changes.

Comment: "realm.write(() => disallows any other writes at the same time, and updates the Realm to its latest version when the transaction is opened"

Does this mean that selects that occur within a realm write transaction are always looking at the latest data?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I meant - and that's actually something to beware because the query conditions are immediately evaluated when there is a change. For example, you have `someBool = true` as a query condition, you set it to false on an object that you got from that results, then that object will no longer be in that results unless it's a result snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Realm does not allow concurrent writes. There is at most one ongoing
write transaction at any point in time.

If the async getNextJob() function is called twice concurrently, one of
the invocations will block on realm.write().

SELECT FOR UPDATE then works trivially, since there are no concurrent updates.